# What is the meaning of list[:] in this code?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, iteration

This code is from Python's Documentation. I'm a little confused.

```
words = ['cat', 'window', 'defenestrate']
for w in words[:]:
    if len(w) > 6:
        words.insert(0, w)
print(words)
```

And the following is what I thought at first:

```
words = ['cat', 'window', 'defenestrate']
for w in words:
    if len(w) > 6:
        words.insert(0, w)
print(words)
```

Why does this code create a infinite loop and the first one doesn't?

Comment: coz, you are inserting an element to `words` list on every iteration -))

Comment: the first one is a copy of the initial `words` not `words` itself

Comment: In the first, you're iterating through a copy of `words` taken before you started adding stuff to it. In the second, you're trying to loop through `words` and making `words` longer at the same time, so you never reach the end.

Comment: The example iterates through a copy of the array, while your's iterates through the list itself. When the copy is made, the new words aren't inserted, so it only loops through the 3 values.

Comment: I would avoid the explicit iteration altogether: `words = [w for w in words if 6 < len(w)] + words`

Comment: Please provide a link to where you found the example.  It is not at https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#for.  If it is anywhere in the official 'Python Documentation' on python.org, we would probably like to change or delete it.

Comment: Just found it.  https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements.  It is being discussed on https://bugs.python.org/issue30826.

Comment: @BhargavRao would it be better to update that as a duplicate of this rather than vice versa? The accepted answer is terse (a pathological problem associated with that particular user).

Comment: You can always add a better answer there @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ. FWIW, the brief answer there does explain the reasoning behind the issue here.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

This is one of the gotchas! of python, that can escape beginners.

The `words[:]` is the magic sauce here.

Observe:

```
>>> words =  ['cat', 'window', 'defenestrate']
>>> words2 = words[:]
>>> words2.insert(0, 'hello')
>>> words2
['hello', 'cat', 'window', 'defenestrate']
>>> words
['cat', 'window', 'defenestrate']
```

And now without the `[:]`:

```
>>> words =  ['cat', 'window', 'defenestrate']
>>> words2 = words
>>> words2.insert(0, 'hello')
>>> words2
['hello', 'cat', 'window', 'defenestrate']
>>> words
['hello', 'cat', 'window', 'defenestrate']
```

The main thing to note here is that `words[:]` returns a `copy` of the existing list, so you are iterating over a copy, which is not modified.

You can check whether you are referring to the same lists using `id()`:

In the first case:

```
>>> words2 = words[:]
>>> id(words2)
4360026736
>>> id(words)
4360188992
>>> words2 is words
False
```

In the second case:

```
>>> id(words2)
4360188992
>>> id(words)
4360188992
>>> words2 is words
True
```

It is worth noting that `[i:j]` is called the *slicing operator*, and what it does is it returns a fresh copy of the list starting from index `i`, upto (but not including) index `j`.

So, `words[0:2]` gives you

```
>>> words[0:2]
['hello', 'cat']
```

Omitting the starting index means it defaults to `0`, while omitting the last index means it defaults to `len(words)`, and the end result is that you receive a copy of the *entire* list.

---

If you want to make your code a little more readable, I recommend the `copy` module.

```
from copy import copy 

words = ['cat', 'window', 'defenestrate']
for w in copy(words):
    if len(w) > 6:
        words.insert(0, w)
print(words)
```

This basically does the same thing as your first code snippet, and is much more readable.

Alternatively (as mentioned by DSM in the comments) and on python >=3, you may also use `words.copy()` which does the same thing.

Comment: @Coldspeed of course - you could just write it as `words[:] = [w for w in words if len(w) > 6][::-1] + words`....

Comment: Jon, I did mention "more readability", not less... :P

Comment: @Coldspeed More readability: `words[:0] = [w for w in words if len(w) > 6]`.

Comment: I would recommend emphasizing using `is` over `id()` to see whether you have distinct objects, since `id()` numbers can be reused when objects go out of scope and are freed, which is especially likely if you're playing with the interactive Python console.

Comment: `list(words)` seems to work as well as `copy(words)` and doesn't require an import.

Answer (score 11):

`words[:]` copies all the elements in `words` into a new list. So when you iterate over `words[:]`, you're actually iterating over all the elements that `words` currently has. So when you modify `words`, the effects of those modifications are not visible in `words[:]` (because you called on `words[:]` before starting to modify `words`)

In the latter example, you are iterating over `words`, which means that any changes you make to `words` is indeed visible to your iterator. As a result, when you insert into index 0 of `words`, you "bump up" every other element in `words` by one index. So when you move on to the next iteration of your for-loop, you'll get the element at the next index of `words`, but that's just the element that you just saw (because you inserted an element at the beginning of the list, moving all the other element up by an index).

To see this in action, try the following code:

```
words = ['cat', 'window', 'defenestrate']
for w in words:
    print("The list is:", words)
    print("I am looking at this word:", w)
    if len(w) > 6:
        print("inserting", w)
        words.insert(0, w)
        print("the list now looks like this:", words)
print(words)
```

Answer (score 6):

(In addition to @Coldspeed answer)

Look at the below examples:

```
words = ['cat', 'window', 'defenestrate']
words2 = words
words2 is words
```

results: `True`

It means names `word` and `words2` refer to the same object.

```
words = ['cat', 'window', 'defenestrate']
words2 = words[:]
words2 is words
```

results: `False`

In this case, we have created the new object.

Answer (score 1):

Let's have a look at iterator and iterables:

> An iterable is an object that has an `__iter__` method which returns an
>   iterator, or which defines a `__getitem__` method that can take
>   sequential indexes starting from zero (and raises an `IndexError` when
>   the indexes are no longer valid). So an iterable is an object that you
>   can get an iterator from.

An iterator is an object with a `next` (Python 2) or `__next__` (Python 3) method.

`iter(iterable)` returns iterator object, and `list_obj[:]` returns a new list object, exact copy of list_object.

In your first case:

```
for w in words[:]
```

The `for` loop will iterate over new copy of the list not the original words. Any change in words has no effect on loop iteration, and the loop terminates normally.

This is how the loop does its work:

1. loop calls `iter` method on iterable and iterates over the iterator
2. loop calls `next` method on iterator object to get next item from iterator. This step is repeated until there are no more elements left
3. loop terminates when a `StopIteration` exception is raised.

In your second case:

```
words = ['cat', 'window', 'defenestrate']
for w in words:
    if len(w) > 6:
        words.insert(0, w)
print(words)
```

You are iterating over the original list words and adding elements to words have a direct impact on the iterator object. So every time your words is updated, the corresponding iterator object is also updated and therefore creates an infinite loop.

Look at this:

```
>>> l = [2, 4, 6, 8]
>>> i = iter(l) # returns list_iterator object which has next method
>>> next(i)
2
>>> next(i)
4
>>> l.insert(2, 'A')
>>> next(i)
'A'
```

Every time you update your original list before `StopIteration` you will get the updated iterator and `next` returns accordingly. That's why your loop runs infinitely.

For more on iteration and the iteration protocol you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884132/what-exactly-are-pythons-iterator-iterable-and-iteration-protocols).